# Which step is the correct way of solving this literal equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

$ {a(b-2)\over c-3}=x $ for b.

I solved it two different ways.

1. ${ab-2a\over c-3}=x$

   ${ab-2a\over c-3} *(c-3)=x*(c-3)$

   $ab-2a=cx-3x$

   $ab-2a+2a=cx-3x+2a$

   $ab=cx-3x+2a$

   Therefore $b={cx-3x+2a\over a}$

And the second way

$ {a(b-2)\over c-3}=x $

$ {a(b-2)\over c-3}*(c-3)=x*(c-3) $

$ a(b-2)=x(c-3)$

$ a(b-2)/a=x(c-3)/a$

$ b-2= {x(c-3)\over a}$

$b-2+2= {x(c-3)\over a}+2 $

Therefore  $b={x(c-3)\over a}+2 $

The answers came out differently. Which one is the correct one and which one should I use?

@b00n heT For that factoring, I do not need the answer, because I know what it is (calculator). I just don't  understand how to do it.

Comment: Are your answers different? Try combining the 2 terms in your second answer into one fraction.

Comment: Your two answers are the same: $$\frac{x(c-3)}a+2=\frac{cx-3x}a+\frac{2a}a=\frac{cx-3x+2a}a\;.$$

Comment: Looks can be deceiving

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are correct, and their answers are actually the same. The difference between the two is just a matter of form. I will show this below by rewriting the answer from part 1 as the answer from part 2.

${cx-3x+2a\over a} = \frac{cx-3x}{a}+\frac{2a}{a} = \frac{x(c-3)}{a}+2 $

I concatenated a few steps because I suspected that you had trouble seeing the first equality. Let me know if you need further explanation.